# How to turn on console output in Android Unit tests?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Is there any way to turn on the test logging in the console output?

I know that we can look at the test results generated in a HTML file and check standard output there, but I find it a little bit inconvinient.

I know that there is a way to do this with standard java plugin:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}
```

But using it in an Android project causes an error:

```
Could not find method test()
```

Applying java plugin is unacceptable, of course, as it's not compatible with Android plugins.

Comment: Which console do you mean? All logs are came from device. `Logcat` tool fetches all logs.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express myself clear enough. I meant Android unit tests performed on JVM, started from simple terminal via gradle wrapper (so logcat is out of question)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
android {

...

  testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
        // All the usual Gradle options.
            testLogging {
                events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
                outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
                showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

In my case, I followed this [document](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Running-from-Gradle) and added the `testLogging` option as above. This should printout the log for the unit tests written under `src/test` folder but not the `src/androidTest` one. At the moment of this answer, I was using Android Studio 2.0 preview and gradle 2.8. The commands were `./gradlew test` and `./gradlew test --continue`in which ran in iTerm 2.

Comment: For running the test under `src/androidTest`, I right click the package and choose `Run 'Tests in 'com.example... ` using Android Studio.

Answer (score 8):

This should do it

```
android {

...

  testOptions.unitTests.all {
    testLogging {
      events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/LwZiKTnj8Bc

Answer (score 3):

Even more pretty solution than @ninjahoahong's (Thanks to [Tricky Android blog](http://trickyandroid.com/gradle-tip-4-log-unit-test-execution-events-into-console/)).

Just add next code to your project level `build.gradle` to `allprojects`' body:

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    tasks.matching {it instanceof Test}.all {
        testLogging.events = ["failed", "passed", "skipped"]
    }
}
```