# Stack trace for failing Android instrumentation tests (not unit tests!) in terminal

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[How to turn on console output in Android Unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832144/how-to-turn-on-console-output-in-android-unit-tests) shows how to get stack trace for failing Android unit tests run using Gradle from the terminal. But not for instrumentation tests (i.e. ones in `src/androidTest`) and [`TestOptions`](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.html) doesn't seem to have a section called `androidTests`, `instrumentationTests` or something like that, as opposed to `unitTests`. How can I get these stack traces?